# Highcharts - only show tooltip when hovering directly on point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The default experience for highcharts seems to be that the closest point to your cursor (horizontally) is in a hover state.  This means that a tooltip is triggered when you get more than halfway toward the next point in the line.  I want to have a tooltip trigger when I hover directly over a point, and then remain active until I hover directly over a different point.

Here is a fiddle of the issue, with the corresponding code below:

http://jsfiddle.net/qNLu2/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related with pointTracker, which is used by Line chart, but you can use scatter series and setting lineWidth:

http://jsfiddle.net/qNLu2/1/

```
 chart: {

        type: 'scatter'
    },

    series: [{
        lineWidth:2,
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Firstly, you are missing `type` field inside `series`, which is mandatory if you use Typescript. So if you add that field and specify `scatter` there too, you won't achieve the same UI as with `spline` chart. 
Also, tooltips are still showing when hovering over the lines. Maybe it worked in 2013, idk, but now it doesn't.

Comment: Hi @Akbar, It is working fine with the `scatter` series type and disabled `stickyTracking`, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jdpvnL5m/ A small core modification is required if you want to achieve the same behaviour with `spline` series. Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mLgyobh0/

Answer (score 34):

Using the HighCharts options you can set the following to achieve the effect you want:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stickyTracking: false
    }
},
tooltip: {
    snap: 0
}
```

This will cause the tooltip to trigger only when the mouse is directly over the point and turn off when the mouse leaves the point. The only problem with this is that the fade out animation (i.e. snap: 0) takes some time, but you should be able to change the animation time. I haven't found it yet though.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!! Anyhow up voted

Comment: The difference between this answer and the accepted answer is that here, with stickyTracking, the tooltip is still shown when hovering over the line, not only over the point. That's why @Sebestian Bochan suggested using scatter with lineWidth - to get rid of the line tracker.