# Mouse behavior buggy?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem with this highcharts [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9q2m9wp/).

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
      lang: {
        "noData": "no Data from 01.07.2016 until 01.08.2016"
      },
      "title": {
        "text": ""
      },
      "series": [{
        "zIndex": 10,
        "color": "#2f7ed8",
        "name": "Series 1",
        "stickyTracking": false,
        "marker": {
          "symbol": "square",
          "radius": 5
        },
        "lineWidth": 0,
        "data": [{
        "y": 291.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 10, 10, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 156.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 10, 13, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 215.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 10, 16, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 212.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 10, 18, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 232.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 10, 21, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 73.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 10, 23, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 112.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 11, 7, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 264.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 11, 9, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 152.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 11, 11, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 138.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 11, 12, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 133.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 11, 14, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 272.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 11, 16, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 106.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 11, 20, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 239.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 11, 22, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 220.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 11, 23, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 257.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 12, 8, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 140.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 12, 10, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 86.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 12, 12, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 96.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 12, 13, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 230.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 12, 16, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 262.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 12, 18, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 133.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 12, 20, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 167.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 12, 22, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 59.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 13, 7, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 207.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 13, 10, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 133.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 13, 12, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 127.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 13, 19, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 207.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 13, 21, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 88.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 14, 8, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 161.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 14, 11, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 142.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 14, 13, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 155.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 14, 15, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 197.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 14, 18, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 310.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 14, 22, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 89.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 15, 0, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 182.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 15, 8, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 96.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 15, 11, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 70.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 15, 13, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 111.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 15, 14, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 233.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 15, 16, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 191.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 15, 17, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 162.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 15, 21, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 248.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 16, 9, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 77.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 16, 11, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 94.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 16, 13, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 100.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 16, 16, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 101.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 16, 18, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 154.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 16, 21, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 162.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 17, 0, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 132.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 17, 11, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 151.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 17, 15, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 144.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 17, 18, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 84.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 17, 21, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 136.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 17, 23, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 55.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 18, 4, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 131.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 18, 6, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 182.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 18, 10, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 203.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 18, 12, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 332.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 18, 15, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 177.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 18, 21, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 85.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 18, 23, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 63.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 19, 9, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 189.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 19, 10, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 170.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 19, 11, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 175.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 19, 15, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 204.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 19, 17, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 169.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 19, 18, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 115.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 19, 21, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 117.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 20, 8, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 83.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 20, 10, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 49.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 20, 11, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 195.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 20, 15, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 273.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 20, 17, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 227.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 20, 19, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 243.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 20, 22, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 190.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 20, 23, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 170.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 21, 0, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 86.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 21, 8, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 311.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 21, 10, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 244.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 21, 11, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 129.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 21, 13, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 119.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 21, 15, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 125.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 21, 19, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 206.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 21, 21, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 230.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 21, 23, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 229.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 22, 0, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 137.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 22, 8, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 118.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 22, 10, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 57.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 22, 13, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 211.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 22, 15, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 88.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 22, 19, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 290.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 22, 22, 30, 0),
      },{
        "y": 268.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 25, 20, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 297.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 25, 21, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 265.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 25, 22, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 236.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 26, 8, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 249.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 26, 10, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 181.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 26, 11, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 250.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 26, 12, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 241.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 26, 15, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 270.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 26, 17, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 225.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 26, 18, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 146.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 26, 20, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 143.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 26, 21, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 88.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 26, 22, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 98.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 27, 0, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 144.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 27, 8, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 295.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 27, 10, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 256.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 27, 11, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 214.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 27, 16, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 179.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 27, 19, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 191.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 27, 21, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 160.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 28, 0, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 95.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 28, 9, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 138.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 28, 12, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 104.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 28, 13, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 165.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 28, 17, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 185.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 28, 18, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 338.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 28, 21, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 286.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 28, 23, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 131.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 29, 3, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 98.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 29, 8, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 205.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 29, 10, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 130.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 29, 11, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 80.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 29, 13, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 246.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 29, 16, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 183.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 29, 18, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 199.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 29, 19, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 219.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 29, 21, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 318.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 29, 23, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 156.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 30, 8, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 73.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 30, 11, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 98.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 30, 11, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 105.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 30, 14, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 194.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 30, 17, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 183.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 30, 20, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 289.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 30, 21, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 350.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 31, 0, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 242.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 31, 8, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 240.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 31, 10, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 146.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 31, 11, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 117.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 31, 13, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 191.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 31, 15, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 189.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 31, 17, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 153.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 31, 20, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 161.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 143.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1, 0, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 62.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1, 8, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 98.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1, 13, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 166.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1, 14, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 202.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1, 17, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 273.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1, 21, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 240.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 2, 0, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 145.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 2, 8, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 87.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 2, 12, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 163.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 2, 16, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 196.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 2, 19, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 347.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 2, 22, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 200.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 3, 0, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 132.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 3, 8, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 251.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 3, 10, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 254.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 3, 12, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 94.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 3, 14, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 88.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 3, 18, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 247.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 3, 21, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 179.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 109.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 4, 10, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 67.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 4, 12, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 172.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 4, 15, 30, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 96.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 4, 17, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 116.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 4, 18, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 111.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 4, 21, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 234.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 4, 22, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 187.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 72.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 5, 9, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 266.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 5, 11, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 237.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 5, 13, 15, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 268.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 5, 16, 45, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 261.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 5, 18, 0, 0),
      }, {
        "y": 140.0,
        "x": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 5, 21, 30, 0),
      }],
        "tooltip": {
          "pointFormat": "<span style=\"color:{series.color}\">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ",
          "useHTML": true,
          "crosshairs": true
        }
      }, {
        "zIndex": 11,
        "color": "#D6487E",
        "name": "Series 2",
        "marker": {
          "symbol": "triangle-down",
          "radius": 5
        },
        "lineWidth": 0,
        "data": [],
        "tooltip": {
          "pointFormat": "<span style=\"color:{series.color}\">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ",
          "useHTML": true,
          "crosshairs": true
        }
      }, {
        "zIndex": 10,
        "color": "#2f7ed8",
        "name": "Series 3",
        "marker": {
          "symbol": "triangle",
          "radius": 5
        },
        "lineWidth": 0,
        "data": [],
        "tooltip": {
          "pointFormat": "<span style=\"color:{series.color}\">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ",
          "useHTML": true,
          "crosshairs": true
          }
        }, {
        "enableMouseTracking": false,
        "zIndex": 3,
        "isThreshold": true,
        "name": "Background series",
        "color": "#edf9d2",
        "type": "arearange",
        "data": [
         [Date.UTC(2015, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0), 80.0, 160.0],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 10, 23, 59, 59), 80.0, 160.0],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 10, 23, 59, 59), 80.0, 160.0]
        ],
        "scalingFix": true

      }, {
        "zIndex": 10,
        "color": "#2f7ed8",
        "name": "Test series",
        "marker": {
          "symbol": "circle",
          "radius": 5
        },
        "lineWidth": 0,
        "data": [],
        "tooltip": {
          "pointFormat": "<span style=\"color:{series.color}\">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ",
          "useHTML": true,
          "crosshairs": true
        }
      }, {
        "name": "scaling-fix",
        "data": [
          [Date.UTC(2016, 6, 31, 23, 59, 59), 80.0],
          [Date.UTC(2016, 7, 1, 23, 59, 59), 80.0]
        ],
        "zIndex": 0,
        "visible": false,
        "type": "line",
        "showInLegend": false
      } ],
      "yAxis": {
        "minRange": 20,
        "startOnTick": true,
        "plotBands": [],
        "title": {
          "text": "Values",
          "enabled": true
        },
        "gridZIndex": 0,
        "min": 0,
        "endOnTick": false,
        "plotLines": [],
        "tickInterval": 20
      },
      "chart": {
        "zoomType": "x",
        "marginLeft": 70,
        "resetZoomButton": {
          "theme": {
            "states": {
              "hover": {
                "style": {
                  "color": "white"
                },
                "fill": "#DA5430"
              }
            },
            "stroke": "#DA5430",
            "r": 0,
            "style": {
              "color": "white"
            },
            "fill": "#DA5430"
          }
        },
        "type": "line",
      },
      "tooltip": {

        "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
          "millisecond": "%A, %e. %b., %H:%M:%S.%L",
          "week": "Woche von %A, %e. %b. %Y",
          "hour": "%A, %e. %b., %H:%M",
          "month": "%B %Y",
          "second": "%A, %e. %b., %H:%M:%S",
          "year": "%Y",
          "day": "%A, %e. %b. %Y",
          "minute": "%A, %e. %b., %H:%M"
        },
        "snap": 0,
        "shared": false,
        "followPointer": false,
        "useHTML": true
      },
      "credits": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "plotOptions": {
        "series": {
          "states": {
            "hover": {
              "lineWidth": 0,
              "lineWidthPlus": 0
            }
          },
          "cursor": "pointer",
          "stickyTracking": false
        },
        "line": {
          "zIndex": 6,
          "marker": {
            "enabled": true
          },
          "stickyTracking": false,
          "dataLabels": {
            "enabled": false,
            "useHTML": true
          }
        },
        "arearange": {},
        "scatter": {
          "marker": {
            "enabled": true
          },
          "stickyTracking": false,
          "dataLabels": {
            "enabled": false,
            "useHTML": true
          }
        },
        "area": {
          "stacking": true,
          "enableMouseTracking": false,
          "marker": {
            "enabled": false
          },
          "shadow": false,
          "lineWidth": 0,
          "showInLegend": false
        }
      },
      "xAxis": {
        "minRange": 60000,
        "min": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0),
        "minPadding": 0.0,
        "plotBands": [{
          "zIndex": -100,
          "to": Date.UTC(2016, 6, 3, 21, 59, 59),
          "from": Date.UTC(2016, 6, 1, 22, 0, 0),
          "color": "rgba(200,200,200,0.1)"
        }, {
          "zIndex": -100,
          "to": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 6, 22, 59, 59),
          "from": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 4, 23, 0, 0),
          "color": "rgba(200,200,200,0.1)"
        }, {
          "zIndex": -100,
          "to": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 13, 22, 59, 59),
          "from": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 11, 23, 0, 0),
          "color": "rgba(200,200,200,0.1)"
        }, {
          "zIndex": -100,
          "to": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 20, 22, 59, 59),
          "from": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 18, 23, 0, 0),
          "color": "rgba(200,200,200,0.1)"
        }, {
          "zIndex": -100,
          "to": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 27, 22, 59, 59),
          "from": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 25, 23, 0, 0),
          "color": "rgba(200,200,200,0.1)"
        }],
        "plotLines": [{
          "zIndex": -100,
          "width": 2,
          "dashStyle": "ShortDash",
          "color": "rgba(200,200,200,0.3)",
          "value": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 6, 23, 0, 0)
        }, {
          "zIndex": -100,
          "width": 2,
          "dashStyle": "ShortDash",
          "color": "rgba(200,200,200,0.3)",
          "value": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 13, 23, 0, 0)
        }, {
          "zIndex": -100,
          "width": 2,
          "dashStyle": "ShortDash",
          "color": "rgba(200,200,200,0.3)",
          "value": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 20, 23, 0, 0)
        }, {
          "zIndex": -100,
          "width": 2,
          "dashStyle": "ShortDash",
          "color": "rgba(200,200,200,0.3)",
          "value": Date.UTC(2015, 11, 27, 23, 0, 0)
        }],
        "gridZIndex": 0,
        "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
          "millisecond": "%H:%M:%S.%L",
          "week": "%e. %b. %y",
          "hour": "%H:%M",
          "month": "%B %y",
          "second": "%H:%M:%S",
          "year": "%Y",
          "day": "%e. %b. %y",
          "minute": "%H:%M"
        },
        "gridLineWidth": 0,
        "maxPadding": 0.0,
        "endOnTick": false,
        "max": Date.UTC(2016, 0, 10, 23, 59, 59),
        "minTickInterval": 60000,
        "type": "datetime",
        "events": {
          "afterSetExtremes": function() {
            var axis = "xAxis";
            var axis2 = "yAxis";
            var chartgroup = null;
            if (typeof charts_p_allchartsmodule != 'undefined') {
              chartgroup = charts_p_allchartsmodule;
            }
            if (typeof charts_container != 'undefined' && charts_container['p_allchartsmodule']) {
              chartgroup = charts_container['p_allchartsmodule'];
            }
            if (chartgroup && this.chart.controllingChart == true) {
              if (this.chart.inverted == true) {
                var min = this.chart.xAxis[0].min;
                var max = this.chart.xAxis[0].max;
              } else {
                var min = this.chart.xAxis[0].min;
                var max = this.chart.xAxis[0].max;
              }
              for (key in chartgroup) {
                if (this.chart != chartgroup[key]) {
                  if (chartgroup[key].inverted == true) {
                    chartgroup[key].xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max, true);
                  } else {
                    chartgroup[key].xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max, true);
                  }
                }
              }
              this.chart.controllingChart = false;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "exporting": {
        "url": "/m/hc-export/",
        "chartOptions": {
          "rangeSelector": {
            "enabled": false
          },
          "navigator": {
            "enabled": false
          },
          "scrollbar": {
            "enabled": false
          }
        }
      },
      "rangeSelector": {
        "buttons": [{
          "text": "Alle",
          "type": "all"
        }],
        "inputEnabled": false,
        "enabled": true
      },
      "type": "scatter",
      "legend": {
      "draggable":true,
      "floating":true, 
  "verticalAlign": "top",
        "zIndex": 2000,
        "title": {
          "text": ":: Legend"
        },
        "itemStyle": {
          "fontSize": "8px"
        },
        "align": "left",
        "draggable": true,
        "borderWidth": 1,
        "backgroundColor": "rgba(234, 234, 234,0.8)",
        "floating": true
      }
  });
});
```

When you hover over on of the points it will  select a other point with nearly the same X-Axis. The Y-Axis is switching up and down but not to the point where the mouse hovers over. So the selection behavior isn´t precise, so you can´t see the right tooltip where your mouse hovers over.

[Mouse = red dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sArgq.png)

Please have a look at it.

Comment: tooltips are activated by proximity to the x axis value of a point. So it will trigger if your mouse moves closer - along the x axis - to another point, regardless of y axis position. (I don't have a solution, just an FYI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series is treated as a "line" chart, which causes this behaviour of the tooltip popup. I found a problem in your configuration object. The `type:"scatter"` option must be placed in the `"chart":{}` object.

```
chart:{
   type:"scatter"
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/u9q2m9wp/2/

see also: [Highcharts - only show tooltip when hovering directly on point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825459/highcharts-only-show-tooltip-when-hovering-directly-on-point)